# Nutch 1.14 - not crawling all links in the page

Tags: solr, web-crawler, nutch

I have got nutch 1.14 working with Solr 6.4.2
Nutch not crawling (following through) all links in the page

```
<property>
  <name>db.ignore.internal.links</name>
  <value>false</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>db.ignore.external.links</name>
  <value>false</value>
</property>
```

Comment: I am crawling http://nutch.apache.org/  site so assume there is no robots issue. regex-urlfilter is default without modifications. 
# accept anything else
+.

Comment: Could you specify with which parameters are you running Nutch? which links are missing? Have you changed anything else in the configuration?

Answer (score 1):

There are very many possibilities here, the nutch-site.xml houses many many properties.

Have you checked this one:

```
<property>
   <name>db.max.outlinks.per.page</name>
   <value>100</value>
   <description>The maximum number of outlinks that we'll process for a page.
       If this value is nonnegative (>=0), at most db.max.outlinks.per.page outlinks
       will be processed for a page; otherwise, all outlinks will be processed.
   </description>
</property>
```